Why my terminal integrated in vs code doesn't work suddenly
I have a Chromebook and I use vs code every day. Today, as soon as I open the integrated terminal, the whole vs code page jumps, black screen, then returns to normal...and then I can't click on anything. I have to close vs code.
Does anyone have a solution please?
Thanks
I've uninstalled vs code, removed linux from my chromebook, set my chromebook to 0, reinstalled everything...and still the same, I can't use the terminal, which makes vs code jump

Have you checked for issues on the VS Code GitHub page?

I found a solution on Reddit saying to open VSC with code --disable-gpu - tried it on my Chromebook and it solves the issue for me.

I had the same problem on my Chromebook with Snapdragon. Instead of running all VS Code with the --disable-gpu flag and disabling GPU acceleration for whole editor, the solution is to add the following line to settings.json: "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off".

I resolved the similear issue by the following steps:

Click on the 'Manage' icon
Go to Settings (Ctrl+Comma)
On 'Search Settings' input field, type terminal
Under 'Features' click on 'Terminal'
Scroll down the page untill you find 'Terminal > Integrated: Gpu Acceleration' which is to Controls whether the terminal will leverage the GPU to do its rendering.
From drop-down select off

Done! Open the terminal, it should work as expected.

I have also been facing this problem so literally a month but i haven't found any solution for same . But out of curiosity i stick to it and tried following every possible way. After so much research i have found that with new version of vs code when we are trying to open integrated terminal its showing black screen . Here is the resolution of same .
1-Make sure you get the shortcut of VS Code when you install vs code
2- once vs code is installed , right click the desktop app/shortcut and navigate and click properties , then in the top right click compatibility.
3- You will be seeing Run this program in compatibilty mode for is checked , uncheck it and save these settings by applying same .
4 Restart your vs code and boom everything is working fine Vs code terminal showing blank screen resolution

Chromebook is not Windows. Its VS Code runs in a Linux container. There is no compatibility settings.
